# how to create custom 401 error page in mvc using windows authentification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to make custom `401 (unauthorized) page` using `mvc 5` with windows authentification
I inherited my `AuthorizeEnumAttribute` from `AuthorizeAttribute` and marked actions with it. nothing special.

By default if user has access(isinrole) page is shown and if not it show standard browser dialog for login/password. if user entered credentials which does not in particular role it ask credentials again.
After user click cancel I see standard IIS error page `"HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized"`

Can I replace this page somehow with my own when user click cancel?

I tried `override HandleUnauthorizedRequest` and add `httpError` in `web.config` but both redirect to custom page in case unauthorize user but do not ask credentials what does not fit my needs.

I see in fiddler that after cancel there is no requests to server and after cancel it show iis 401 page received previously

Is there any way to show my html after cancel?

thanks in advance.